# Method Post Stopped Working on Classic ASP Form

Tags: forms, post, methods, asp-classic

I created a form where users sign up for something and used the form method=post. This form worked find for years without problem. Recently we moved from Windows Server 2003 to Windows Server 2012, nothing else changed. Now, after the form summits it is not holding the data in the table fields. If I switch the method to method=get the form works, but the data entered in the form becomes part of the url which is undesirable.

Form example, user enters their email address, after the action I look for the email address in a MySQL database to check if the user has already signed up using that email address:

```
<FORM NAME="Sign_Up" ACTION="Email_Submit.asp" METHOD=POST>
<table class="form" align=center>
    <tr>
        <td class="b">
        Email: <INPUT class="texta" id=text2 name=Email>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="b2">
            <INPUT type='submit' value=' Submit Request ' id=submit1 name=submit1>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

on the page it submits when I try to request the information from the form I get nothing:

```
SQL = "select * FROM info WHERE Email = '" & Request("Email") & "'"
```

when I Request("Email") I get nothing in return so the SQL statement looks like this:

```
select * FROM info WHERE Email = ''
```

Any clue why method=post would stop working, could it be something set on the server not allowing the page to retain the information?

Comment: Have you tried testing what `Request.Form("Email")` returns?

Comment: also, add type=text into <INPUT class="texta" id=text2 name=Email>

Comment: Why so inconsistent with quoting attribute values? `table class="form" align=center>`... `INPUT class="texta" id=text2`... `type='submit' id=submit1`. Double quotes, single quotes, no quotes! You're really putting my OCD on edge here!

Comment: I'm with @Bond here: the utterly random quoting, or lack thereof, of attribute values is really bugging me. In fact, I'm wondering if it's bugging the server as well: maybe the new server has stricter validation. Add quotes to ALL of your attributes (rather than just a random sample of them) and see if the form works better.

Comment: I tend to agree with @Zam it's more likely the lack of `type` attribute on the `input` element for `Email`.

Comment: Sloppy syntax aside, the form worked on the old server. I suspect it has more to do with the fact the site is now behind an F5 firewall, but my network admin isn't responding so I'm left in limbo as to where to go next. This is only affecting forms where the action go to a new page, and from that don't have a cert. I'm thinking the F5 is dropping anything come in without a cert. Copied all the files to another server that is not on the F5 and it works.

Comment: @EdW. Sounds like you've hit the nail on the head.

Comment: @EdW.: why didn't you put that information about the firewall in your question? Do you enjoy making us chase wild geese?

Comment: Regardless of what it "should" allow, using proper conventions is preferable to random quirks, and helps people to focus on real potential issues. Also, I'm not sure I understood about SSL: are you submitting from SSL into non-SSL or vice versa? I'd avoid crossing those lines, as well, as it will be a concern for users when they see a nasty potential security threat warning as they submit their data.

Answer (score 0):

same problem for me on server 2012

replace -request.form- to -request-

it works for me

Answer (score -1):

Use `Request.Form("Email")` for get value. You sending data in POST request. You could try to change POST request to GET request, then you need to use `Request.QueryString("Email")`

Comment: The `Request("Email")` should work fine it's just a away of accessing the whole collection of `QueryString` and `Form` elements. The issue will be elsewhere.